# How can I persist certificates in Java's cacerts?

Tags: ldap, java, ssl-certificate, update, keystore

We need to have a certificate in Java's cacerts keystore for one of our servers that is authenticated by LDAP. We are using Ubuntu server.

We have successfully done this by updating the cacerts file in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security` but occasionally a Java update is installed and the cacerts file seems to be getting replaced by a default one that doesn't contain our changes.

This doesn't happen very often but it is becoming a bit of a pain when it does happen. Is there a better way of adding things to cacerts so that they don't get lost when a Java update happens?

Comment: depending on distribution, you can force the packet manager not to update the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the server certificate signed by a CA, then you don't have do it at all.

If you really can't do that, which you really should, Java installs its own cacerts file when it updates so you will just have to cope with it.